# How to exclude one word from python list?

Tags: python, regex, list

I am trying to work on Python Regex. I have a list as follows:

```
['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-2', 'MYTAB-PERF','ABC','DEF']
```

I need to select all values start with `MYTAB`, excluding `MYTAB-2`.
Result should be :

```
['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-PERF']
```

What should be the regex syntax for it?

Comment: Question needs a little clarification: Is something like `MYTAB-23` valid? I.e., is `MYTAB-2` forbidden as an entire value or just a prefix?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this piece of code.

1. It will loop through the initial list `l1` and if the item `startswith("MYTAB")`, it'll be added to list `l2`
2. It will find the index of `MYTAB-2` inside the `l2` list
3. Remove `MYTAB-2`

**Code:**

```
l1 = ['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-2', 'MYTAB-PERF','ABC','DEF']
l2 = []

for item in l1:
    #add item to l2 if startswith MYTAB
    if item.startswith('MYTAB'):
        l2.append(item)

#getting index of 'MYTAB-2'
index = l2.index('MYTAB-2')

#removing MYTAB-B
del(l2[index])

#printing l2
l2
```

Output:

```
['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-PERF']
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm showing another approach to his problem. this way we both can learn. do you really think you need to downvote this?

Comment: Now that you have added some narrative, I am more than willing to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter with `re` on a list comprehension:

```
import re

l = ['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-2', 'MYTAB-PERF','ABC','DEF']
l = [i  for i in l if re.match(r'MYTAB-[^2]', i)]
print(l)
# ['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-PERF']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> import re
>>> list_ = ['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-2', 'MYTAB-PERF', 'ABC', 'DEF']
>>> filtered_list = filter(lambda str_: re.search(r'^MYTAB(?!-2)', str_), list_)
>>> filtered_list
['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-PERF']
```

Comment: You can get rid of the leading `^` and use `match` instead of `search`. +1 for negative lookahead.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i agree with you but i did it in that way to show more regular expressions syntax like questioner ask.

Comment: More is not better. I don't see where OP asked for more complex regex.

Comment: @MadPhysicist "I need to select all values start with ... What should be the regex syntax for it?" For me `^` tells more about REGEX SYNTAX than `.match()`

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options for filtering the list. The basic answer to your question is `'MYTAB(?!-2)'` if you are using `re.match`, which matches the beginning of the input.

```
import re
expr = re.compile('MYTAB(?!-2)')
rawList = ['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-2', 'MYTAB-PERF','ABC','DEF']
filteredList = [x for x in rawList if expr.match(x)]
```

However, there is a simpler way to do this since you are looking at a prefix:

```
filteredList = [x for x in rawList if x.startswith('MYTAB') and x not x.startswith('MYTAB-2')]
```

If you are not OK with list comprehensions for any reason, you may want to use the builtin `filter` function:

```
filteredList = list(filter(expr.match, rawList))
```

or even

```
filteredList = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('MYTAB') and not x.startswith('MYTAB-2'), rawList))
```

Additionally, if you do not wish to keep a reference to your precompiled expression around (e.g., trading efficiency for brevity), you can use `re.match` instead of `re.compile.match`:

```
import re
rawList = ['MYTAB-EVENTS', 'MYTAB-1', 'MYTAB-2', 'MYTAB-PERF','ABC','DEF']
filteredList = [x for x in rawList if re.match(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `/MYTAB-[^2]+/` for this. The syntax `[^2]` means all except for `2`.

Comment: `[^2]+` the plus sign forces the engine to match all additional characters which are not `2`, so `MYTAB-22` being different than `MYTAB-2` it would not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pyregex to find your regex searches.  Here is a a [link](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6Ik1ZVEFCLVteMl0iLCJmbGFncyI6MCwibWF0Y2hfdHlwZSI6ImZpbmRhbGwiLCJ0ZXN0X3N0cmluZyI6IlsnTVlUQUItRVZFTlRTJywgJ01ZVEFCLTEnLCAnTVlUQUItMicsICdNWVRBQi1QRVJGJywnQUJDJywnREVGXSJ9) to a working regex for your question

In this case it uses `MYTAB-[^2]` as the regex pattern.

Comment: Link only answer. Please post the meat of it here.